# Elasticsearch ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have written an ingest pipeline in elasticsearch, I've tested the messages against it using the simulate end point, however it seems that any log entries that match the grok patterns end up in a black hole rather than hitting the index.

Ingest Pipeline

```
{
  "rtf-access-log-pipeline" : {
    "description" : "Process artifactory access logs",
    "processors" : [
      {
        "grok" : {
          "field" : "message",
          "patterns" : [
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\] %{DATA:rtf.access.repo_name}\\:%{DATA:rtf.access.file_path}\\s+.* %{USERNAME:rtf.access.username}/%{IP:rtf.access.client_ip}",
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\] %{DATA:rtf.access.repo_name}\\:%{DATA:rtf.access.file_path}\\s+.* %{GREEDYDATA:rtf.access.other}",
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\\\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\\\]\\s+for client\\s+:\\s+%{USERNAME:rtf.access.username}\\/%{IP:rtf.access.client_ip}"
          ],
          "on_failure" : [
            {
              "set" : {
                "field" : "error",
                "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "date" : {
          "field" : "rtf.access.timestamp",
          "target_field" : "@timestamp",
          "formats" : [
            "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
          ],
          "timezone" : "Europe/Stockholm",
          "on_failure" : [
            {
              "set" : {
                "field" : "error",
                "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "remove" : {
          "field" : "message"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Filebeat setup for reference, if I comment out the pipeline this works fine.

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - D:/artifactory/logs/access.log
    pipeline: "rtf-access-log-pipeline"


output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "A PASSWORD"


setup.kibana:
  host: "kibana:5601"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "A PASSWORD"
```

How I fired this at the simulate end point

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
  "description":"Process artifactory access logs",
  "processors":[
    {
      "grok":{
        "field":"message",
        "patterns":[
          "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\] %{DATA:rtf.access.repo_name}\\:%{DATA:rtf.access.file_path}\\s+.* %{USERNAME:rtf.access.username}\/%{IP:rtf.access.client_ip}",
          "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\] %{DATA:rtf.access.repo_name}\\:%{DATA:rtf.access.file_path}\\s+.* %{GREEDYDATA:rtf.access.other}",
          """%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:rtf.access.timestamp} \\[%{DATA:rtf.access.action_resp} %{DATA:rtf.access.action_type}\\]\s+for client\s+:\s+%{USERNAME:rtf.access.username}\/%{IP:rtf.access.client_ip}"""
        ],
        "on_failure":[
          {
            "set":{
              "field":"error",
              "value":"{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "date":{
        "field":"rtf.access.timestamp",
        "target_field":"@timestamp",
        "formats":[
          "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
        ],
        "timezone":"Europe/Stockholm",
        "on_failure":[
          {
            "set":{
              "field":"error",
              "value":"{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "remove":{
        "field":"message"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"docs":[
  {
    "_source": {
      "message": """2020-06-05 03:39:28,523 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] product-artefacts-local:org/companylimited/core/chem/org.companylimited.core.input/3.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml  for client : NA / 192.168.5.156."""
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

Simluate Result

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2020-06-05T03:39:28.523+02:00",
          "rtf" : {
            "access" : {
              "file_path" : "org/companylimited/core/chem/org.companylimited.core.input/3.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml",
              "other" : "192.168.5.156.",
              "repo_name" : "product-artefacts-local",
              "action_resp" : "DENIED",
              "action_type" : "DOWNLOAD",
              "timestamp" : "2020-06-05 03:39:28,523"
            }
          }
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-06-08T08:58:24.967662Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by black hole?

Comment: Can you provide a sample record?  The best way to approach ingest pipelines is by testing them with the `/_ingest/pipeline/_simulate` API ahead of time.

Comment: @RyanFoley I've added the request and result for the simulate endpoint I had already tested it that's how I know the grok matched.

Comment: @Val I mean they disappear as in don't go anywhere I can find